# Spring Boot - Multiple context paths - have one redirect to the other?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have a spring boot 2 app that is typically accessed behind a proxy server for all requests at, say, /blah/**.

We set up this app to use a context path called /blah to simplify this (so we no longer had to add /blah to all of our controller mappings, resource imports, etc)

```
server:
  port: 9876
  servlet:
      context-path: /blah
```

This works fine, but there are some cases where people might access the app at root (/) that we'd like to handle.

It looks like I need to create a new servlet that listens to "/" and just redirects to "/blah"? What is the easiest way to set that up? I don't want any of my existing beans in this other context, just a simple controller or html file that performs a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think would be easiest way.

```
@RequestMapping("/*")
public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    response.sendRedirect("/blah");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, since the existing app is under the context /blah, that controller mapping would only listen to /blah/*